# SQL Join and getting count in table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Here is my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dba4ea/5)

I am joining `user` and `address` table for now. Now i need to take the count of the logs table where `in_time` and `out_time` is filled

Here is my SQL Query that i have so far

```
select u.id, u.name, a.address from user u 
left join address a on u.id = a.user_id
where u.id = 1
```

I.e., Output should be like this

```
id  name    address  total_count proper_count
1   Alpha   Chennai  4           3
```

Comment: What does log.user_id refer to? It's a `varchar(50)` which doesn't match any other column in other tables. Using explicit foreign keys would make it a lot easier to understand...

Comment: Hint: use Group By and Count. Also, use NOT NULL on date fields that have no data in the Where condition.

Answer (score 1):

You were just one step back from your expected query. just need another join with log table and use aggregate function

```
select u.id, u.name, a.address,
sum(case when in_time is not null and out_time is not null 
    then 1 else 0 end ) as total_count ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN l.in_time = 0 OR l.out_time = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS proper_count
from user u 
left join address a on u.id = a.user_id
left join log l on u.id=l.user_id
where u.id = 1
group by u.id, u.name, a.address
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2efe0/6

```
id  name    address total_count proper_count
1   Alpha   Chennai   4            3
```

Comment: Can you help me get the correct number of  employees on the basis of Current department? the 'CurrentEmpCount' is to count the number of employees by counting the current department IDs. Should I reference the DepartID as FK in current and default department? And should I use PARTITION by to count and insert data? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9799a/2/8

Comment: @Kopal what is your question

Comment: I wanted to get the correct number of employees on the basis of Current department. But I got the solution now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use below schema design for your requirement. User_id must be INTEGER, and use datetime datatype for in & out time column.

```
CREATE TABLE log (
    id BIGINT,
    user_id BIGINT,
    in_time datetime,
    out_time datetime
);

INSERT INTO log (id,user_id, in_time, out_time) VALUES (1,1,'2018-07-21 06:50:41','2018-07-21 10:50:41');
INSERT INTO log (id,user_id, in_time, out_time) VALUES (2,1,'2018-07-22 06:50:41','2018-07-22 10:50:41');
INSERT INTO log (id,user_id, in_time) VALUES (3,1,'2018-07-23 06:50:41');
INSERT INTO log (id,user_id, in_time, out_time) VALUES (4,1,'2018-07-24 06:50:41','2018-07-22 10:50:41');

select u.id as user_id, u.name, a.address, COUNT(in_time) AS total_count, COUNT(out_time) as proper_count
from log l
INNER JOIN user u on u.id = l.user_id
INNER JOIN address a on a.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id , u.name, a.address
```

Answer (score 0):

You could you this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, a.address, 
    COUNT(*) AS total_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN l.in_time = 0 OR l.out_time = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS proper_count
FROM USER u 
LEFT JOIN address a 
ON u.id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN log l 
ON u.id = l.user_id
WHERE u.id = 1
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, a.address;
```